# Не та форма у числа ответов и вопросов в профиле

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

"350 вопросов" - написано правильно, а вот "4,015 ответы" - должно быть "ответ**ов**".

[image: скриншот]

Аналогичная проблема для вопросов:

[image: вопросов]

Заведён [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368440/339911) на MSE.

Comment: Qwertiy, или возможно было бы лучше оставить любые склонения, а вместо "вопросов" написать "вопросы", если на то пошло: "репутация, reached (лучше бы перевести), ответы, ...ну и вопросы". Мне кажется, так и было задумано. Или нет?

Comment: @Sevastopol', как задумано, не знаю, но по мне нормальный вариант либо "4 015 ответов", либо "ответы: 4 015". А вот "4 015 ответы" - это какая-то фигня, не?

Comment: Qwertiy, ну тогда логика отсутствует в верхней строке с  "репутация" и "reached". Как по мне, так всё должно быть как-то одинаково, а-ля симметрично :)

Comment: Завёл [баг на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368440/339911). Однако, в словах @Sevastopol' есть логика и, следовательно, бага может на самом деле относиться к "вопросам", а не "ответам".

Comment: Кстати, у вопросов тоже форма [единственная и кривенькая используется](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGT99.png).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, у кого-то руки были настолько кривые, что даже формы получились не одинаковые, а разные)))

Comment: Просто исполнители ограничены английским языком интерфейса. Проблемы миноритариев уходят на третий план.